# Problem with ControlValueAccessor - Get Value fired

Tags: angular, angular-providers, controlvalueaccessor

I've created a number picker component:

template:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3 input-md">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text decrease" (click)="decrease();">-</span></div>
  <input [name]="name" [(ngModel)]="value" class="form-control counter" type="number" step="1">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text increase" (click)="increase();" style="border-left: 0px;">+</span></div>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-number-picker',
  templateUrl: './numberPicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./numberPicker.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumberPickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class NumberPickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Output() scoreChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Input()
  name: string;
  @Input() isAdmin: boolean;
  @Input() val: number;
  onChange: any = () => { };
  onTouched: any = () => { };

  get value() {
    console.log(this.val);
    return this.val;
  }

  set value(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.onChange(val);
    this.onTouched();
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  decrease() {
    if (this.value === 0 || this.value === null) {
      if (this.isAdmin) {
        this.value = null;
      } else {
        this.value = 0;
      }
    } else {
      this.value--;
    }
    this.valueIsChanged(this.value);
  }

  increase() {
    if (isNaN(this.value) || this.value === null) {
      this.value = 0;
    } else {
      this.value++;
    }
    this.valueIsChanged(this.value);
  }

  valueIsChanged(value: number) {
    this.scoreChange.emit(value);
  }
}
```

This component is used in ngFor in another component

```
<div let prono of pronos;>
    <app-number-picker [isAdmin]="false" (scoreChange)="prono.pronoEq1 = $event" name="pronoE1" [(ngModel)]="prono.pronoEq1" #score="ngModel"></app-number-picker>
    <app-number-picker [isAdmin]="false" (scoreChange)="prono.pronoEq2 = $event" name="pronoE2" [(ngModel)]="prono.pronoEq2" #score="ngModel"></app-number-picker>
<span [ngbTooltip]="prono.stats">Stats</span>
</div>
```

1- It works but when I change a value with Increase function for example:
- All "get Value()" for all values is triggered (console.log(this.val); in my code)

2- When I get ngbTooltip prono.stats value => "get Value()" for all values is triggered also !

- Why ngbTooltip fired "get Value" of my numberpicker component ?!!!
- Why "get Value" is triggered when I increse/decrease only one value ?!

Please help me to improve my code.

coincoin22

Perhaps, the problem is here :

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumberPickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed get and set function and it works ! Magic ;-)